# Is there a way to view the code of library functions (like strlen, malloc, strcmpr etc.)

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am using a `Linux operating system` and the library functions I am talking about C programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are part of the system's C library, which on most GNU/Linux systems is [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html), also known as "glibc".  Since glibc is open-source free software, you can download its source code and read whatever parts you're interested in.  The [download page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) is the place to start.

Comment: The git repository would be more convenient for someone just wanting to read: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for the open source C libraries. There is glibc, bionic, uclibc and BusyBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) the source code of Glibc, the C library used by most Linux distributions.

It might be a little more complex than you anticipated, though. It might be more helpful to take a look at a simpler C library, if you are interested in how it works in principle. I'd suggest [libctiny](http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the glibc code online from the following location:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/files

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/files/head:/stdlib/

Doug Lea Malloc

ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c

Answer (score 0):

The C library used on most Linux systems is [glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) which is:

> the GNU Project's implementation of the C standard library

and you can browse the [git repository online](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git) and you can find the [download instructions here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't go to see the whole code of any predefined function else you have a very positive reason for that. It is better to see the manual page. To check in manual we have different section and these are
1) simple linux shell scripting command
2) system calls e.g. fork etc 
3) C functions, all predefined function.
7) Some definition of the function
man printf this will redirect you to manual page 1 means you will see the printf of shell scripting
to check for printf c predefined function check 
man 3 printf